# Question about "Python GTK adding signal to a combo box" / answered Apr 24 '10 at 18:21

Tags: python, pygtk

I'm very new to Python and pygtk , I want to  use  the changed value of the combo

in the main window , but I can't !

I need some help

Thanks in advance

Best regards

Comment: Is there any way you can provide a code sample that shows what you tried and what didn't work?  Also, you can paste a link to the other question into this question.  That's much better than a cryptic description.

Answer (score 1):

Without code, it is rather difficult to help for sure, but I'll take a stab at this...

From your question, I am guessing that you're wanting to retrieve the value of the combo box once the user changes it.

You're going to need to create a new event handler to retrieve the value upon the user changing. In order to ensure that the entire module can use this data, we'll start by creating a global variable at the TOP of your module. **This must be above and outside of all classes and definitions!**

```
combo_value = -1
```

Here, we've created a variable called "combo_value", and set it's value to -1. This is important because, first of all, it defines the variable as type 'integer', and second, '-1' is the value returned by the code below if nothing is selected in the combo box.

Now, in the class where you have your pygtk code, put this definition. I prefer putting all my event handlers inside the "__ init __" definition, as it makes them easier to access.

```
def combo_changed(event, data=None):
    #This imports the combo_value variable declared above. Otherwise, the module 
    #would be creating a local variable instead, which would be of no use to the
    #rest of the program.
    global combo_value

    #This retrieves the combo box's selected index and sets the combo_value
    #variable to that index.
    combo_value = combobox.get_active()
```

Now we need to connect our combo box to this event using the "changed" signal.

```
combobox.connect("changed", combo_changed)
```

And there you have it! You can then hook up all of your other processes by checking the value of the combo_value variable. Just remember - **this code sets that variable to the INDEX of the selected item in the combo box, and not the text value!** This is extremely important to remember, because if you try and check for a string in this variable, it'll get you nowhere.

The value will be "-1" if nothing is selected. Remember to count from zero for the index of all your items. It may be useful to write down the values of your combo box and their indexes, for reference. It might look something like this:

> Combobox (choose color) 
>   "Black" - 0 
>   "White" - 1 
>   "Red" - 2 
>   "Green" - 3 
>   "Blue" - 4

Then, in the code for working with the combo box value, you may have a little something like this:

```
if combo_value == -1:
   pass
   #In other words, do nothing at all.
elif combo_value == 0
   #Set color to black
elif combo_value == 1
   #Set color to white
```

And so on, and so forth.

So you can see everything in context, here is the entire code, minus my corny little example above...

```
combo_value = -1

class MyApplication:
   def __init__(self):
       #Your code here.
       def combo_changed(event, data=None):
           #This imports the combo_value variable declared above. Otherwise, the module 
           #would be creating a local variable instead, which would be of no use to the
           #rest of the program.
           global combo_value

           #This retrieves the combo box's selected index and sets the combo_value
           #variable to that index.
           combo_value = combobox.get_active()

       #Your GUI code is here.

       #This is where your combobox is created from a model (we're assuming it is
       #already declared before this point, and called "MyModel".
       combobox = gtk.ComboBox(MyModel)

       #Now we connect the "changed" signal of the combobox to the event we created.
       combobox.connect("changed", combo_changed)
```

I hope this helps! Again, without code, it is very hard to give you specifics. I'm helping you out, since you're new here, but please be sure to post specific examples and code from your project on all future questions.

Cheers!